# Working of the compiler directive in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-directives

The #define compiler directive seems rather strange to me. I have read that **no memory is allocated** to it .

```
#include <iostream>
#define test 50
int main()
{
    cout<<test;
   return 0;
}
```

The above function displays 50 even though no memory is allocated to the compiler directive #define

*How does compiler know that 50 is stored in it (test) without having any memory.*

Comment: Macros perform a simple textual substitution at compile time. Everywhere "test" appears, the compiler substitutes "50". So the program works exactly the same as if you've written `cout<<50;`

Comment: Also, as this is C++ you should really be using `const int test = 50;`. We worked hard when standardizing C++ to make `#define` almost unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Macros](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) are not the same thing as variables.

Your compiler will translate the program

```
#include <iostream>
#define test 50
int main()
{
   cout << test;
   return 0;
}
```

to

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   cout << 50;
   return 0;
}
```

by replacing the name `test` by its value given at your `#define` statement. You might want to take a look at some [tutorials](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) you can find on the internet e.g.:

> ```
> #define getmax(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
> ```
>
> This would replace any occurrence of getmax followed by two arguments
>   by the replacement expression, but also replacing each argument by its
>   identifier, exactly as you would expect if it was a function:
>
> ```
> // function macro
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> #define getmax(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
>
> int main()
> {
>   int x=5, y;
>   y= getmax(x,2);
>   cout << y << endl;
>   cout << getmax(7,x) << endl;
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Very informative :) will surely look at some tutorials!

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, `test` is going to be replaced by `50` whereever it's encountered in the code *prior* to compilation. Because the replacement's not done at runtime there's no overhead.